# How to set a position while we write a string into a file using PHP?

Tags: string, file, position, set

I want to write an attribute inside text field tag, in my file file.txt. Below code writes some content in **file.txt**,

```
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = 'New data line 1';
fwrite($handle, $data);
$new_data = "\n".'New data line 2';
fwrite($handle, $new_data);
```

Below is my form html code,

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="FIrst Name" />
<form>
```

I want to write a name attribute **name="fname"** as below,

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="fname" value="FIrst Name" />
<form>
```

How to set a position while we write a string into a file.